# How to disable hotkey Ctrl + W in Windows 11?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-11, hotkeys

I am running a Windows 11 and I like to play some games. Those games have some hotkeys combinations that frustrate my game, for example, CTRL + W is used many times while in the game, and the result does you know: the game has been closed suddenly.

I have explored many articles on the web and doesn't found anything that helped me to solve the problem. Could you please help me disable the shortcut key CTRL + W in my Windows 11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Test if an application like [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) or [an alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/autohotkey/) can be set to intercept Ctrl-W.

Or

2. Put a small piece of foam rubber or foam polyethylene under the <kbd>W</kbd> or the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, thereby increasing pressure required for a keypress, and providing haptic and kinesthetic feedback. That's what I do to the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key, to avoid "shouting".

Comment: Used AutoHotKey, worked as a charm.